# Python modify value in list of dicts

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am reading a file that contains on each line a dict, but the whole file as a self is not formatted as a dict nor a list.

```
{"key1":"value11", "key2":"value12"}
{"key1":"value21", "key2":"value22"}
```

What I am trying to do is read the file and change the value of some keys.
Something like this.

```
with open(...
    data = reader.read().split("\n")
for dic in data:
    entry = json.loads(dic)
    entry["key"] = "another value"
```

I know if I want to save it to a file I have to open the file again, but it's not even changing in memory, and I am guessing it has to do with how the `for i in data` works, but I wouldn't want to do a copy from every file, mainly because I have a lot of lines.

Is there another way I'm not seeing?

Comment: Assuming you're stuck with this input, Is there any reason you need to *save down* in exactly this format? Pretty inefficient having to call `json.loads` *on each line each time* you need to read the file. I'd rather use a dict of dicts approach.

Comment: Yeah, sadly I get the files in this format and cannot change it, I'm afraid

Comment: Yeh, what I meant is you can do an initial conversion step to convert a "list of dicts" to a single "dict of dicts". Save this down (as `pkl`, `json` or something else) and forget about the old format. But maybe this isn't an option.

Comment: @jpp not sure if it would take more time to do the conversion than using json.loads... Files are around 50Mb full of entries (around 50000 lines), but if it is more efficient I could do the workaround.

Comment: I'd think `pkl` would be fastest. It's already a serialized `dict` in that case.

Comment: @jpp so you'd recommend me to first modify the file so that it is a list/dict of dicts, and then afterwards work with that, right? Any recommendations on how to do that?

Comment: OK, have added an answer to reflect what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For efficiency, I suggest transforming your data into a single dictionary of `dict` objects. You can use line number for indexing.

First read the data into a single dictionary:

```
from io import StringIO
import json, pickle

x = StringIO('''{"key1":"value11", "key2":"value12"}
{"key1":"value21", "key2":"value22"}''')

d = {}

# replace x with open('file.txt', 'r')
with x as fin:
    for idx, line in enumerate(fin):
        d[idx] = json.loads(line.strip())

print(d)

# {0: {'key1': 'value11', 'key2': 'value12'},
#  1: {'key1': 'value21', 'key2': 'value22'}}
```

Then write it to a Pickle file, note `pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL` represents an efficient binary format:

```
filename = r'C:\temp\out.pkl'
# never work with the old format again!
with open(filename, 'wb') as fout:
    pickle.dump(d, fout, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Then read the file again:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as fin:
    d_in = pickle.load(fin)

print(d_in)

# {0: {'key1': 'value11', 'key2': 'value12'},
#  1: {'key1': 'value21', 'key2': 'value22'}}
```

To change a sub-dict is now as trivial as `d[1]['key1'] = 'newval'`.

Do note that Pickling / serialisation is version-specific. However, you should see a large performance improvement through this one-off data restructure.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that the file might be quite big, reasonable approach would be to read the input file line by line, change each line and then write the modified line to the output file.

```
with open('/path/to/output.file') as outfile:
    with open('/path/to/input.file') as inputfile:
        for line in inputfile:
            entry = json.loads(line)
            entry['key'] = 'another value'
            outfile.write(json.dumps(entry) + '\n')
```

**UPD**: regarding your actual problem:

```
with open(...) as reader:
    data = reader.read().split("\n")

for i in range(len(data)):
    entry = data[i]
    entry = json.loads(entry)
    entry["key"] = "another value"
    data[i] = json.dumps(entry)
```

This approach will change `data` in memory. In your snippet on each `for` loop iteration you are creating a temporary variable `entry`, then changing it but then just discarding the result since on the next iteration of the loop you're overwriting it. Also, with `for elem in collection` approach one should not usually modify the collection. In your case the collection is a list of strings, and strings are immutable in python. So, just switch to `for i in range()` approach and then modify elements in the list via overwriting the whole element at position `i`.